# Как в BarChart показывать высоту столбца не относительно самого высокого а с нуля

Tags: java, android, диаграммы

В стандартном режиме в BarChart показывается только размер столбца по сравнению с самым высоким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно, чтобы показывался размер не по сравнению с самым высоким, а с нуля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У меня проблем в том, что 421199 сверху,  а 299506 на дне. Хотя разница у них меньше чем в два раза